# MySQL history ignore

Tags: mysql

So I recently updated to mysql 5.7 from 5.1, and now I notice on this version the up/down arrows do not cycle through the whole history. According to the mysql docs, certain commands related to passwords are no longer logged, but in my case there seems to be a lot more than that. Most of my queries are not logged at all and they are just simple queries like:

```
select table1.email, table1.password, table2.id, table2.ip from table1 join table2 on table1.property1 = table2.property2 order by table2.id;
```

I eventually figured out this is because I have a column called 'password' in one of my tables and mysql will not log this query at all just because it contains the word password. I've gone through a lot of googling, bug reports, mysql docs but there is not a single piece of information about disabling this history ignore behavior, or at least removing some rules from it, there's only instructions on how to add even more rules.

Is there any know solution for this, or do I have to rename my columns and change my stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, this is a feature.

> mysql ignores for logging purposes statements that match any pattern in the “ignore” list. By default, the pattern list is "`*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*`", to ignore statements that refer to passwords.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-logging.html

You can add patterns to the list, but not remove them.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71987